# Trouble using list returned from ansible find module

Tags: list, variables, ansible

I want to create a file in each user home directory.  Based on the debug output it looks like it is returning a dict containing a list called "files" that has all the info I need including user and group to set on the newly created file.  However, it doesn't behave the way I expected and based on everything I am reading I must be misunderstanding how to properly access the variable.  Here is what I am doing:

```
    - name: Get Directory Listing Using Find
      find:
        file_type: directory
        paths: /home
      register: find_user_dirs

    - name: Create Test File in Each Directory
      file:
        status: touch
        path: "{{ item.path }}/test.file"
        owner: root
        group: root
      with_items: "{{ find_user_dirs.files }}"
```

The documentation briefly mentions dicts vs lists, but there seems to be more to it.  I need help to get pointed in the right direction for understanding how to properly use this variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I feel stupid.  Probably because I was working on this at 4am, but still a stupid simple oversight on my part.  I had a typo in there with "status" instead of "state".

After some rest and debugging with the information provided by Rost, which was helpful for other applications by the way, I paid closer attention and found my error.  Now this actually works as intended:

```
    - name: Get Directory Listing Using Find
      find:
        file_type: directory
        paths: /home
      register: find_user_dirs

    - name: Create Test File in Each Directory
      file:
        state: touch
        path: "{{ item.path }}/test.file"
        owner: "{{ item.uid }}"
        group: "{{ item.gid }}"
      with_items: "{{ find_user_dirs.files }}"
```

The classic rookie mistake - seeing what you think you see instead of what you ACTUALLY see.  Sorry to anyone that wasted any time on this.

Answer (score -1):

Well, for me such behavior is quite unexpected too.

But I found the workaround, this works:

```
- name: Create Test File in Each Directory
  file:
      status: touch
      path: "{{ item }}/test.file"
      owner: root
      group: root
  with_items: "{{ find_user_dirs | map(attribute='path') | list }}"
```

Comment: This might be getting me somewhere.  It didn't work for me exactly as you have, but this did give me a result:

      with_items: "{{ find_user_dirs.files | map(attribute='path') | list }}"

It provided a cleaned up list with just the path variables.  This has me thinking the raw variable is a multidimensional dict that the loop can't work with.  The map filter appears to be extracting the specific element and creating a simple list from it.  I will chase this and see what I can do with it.

Thank you.